# SQL Logic: Finding Non-Duplicates with Similar Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I'll do my best to summarize what I am having trouble with. I never used much SQL until recently.

Currently I am using SQL Server 2012 at work and have been tasked with trying to find oddities in SQL tables. Specifically, the tables contain similar information regarding servers. Kind of meta, I know. So they each share a column called "DB_NAME". After that, there are no similar columns. So I need to compare Table A and Table B and produce a list of records (servers) where a server is NOT listed in BOTH Table A and B. Additionally, this query is being ran against an exception list. I'm not 100% sure of the logic to best handle this. And while I would love to get something "extremely efficient", I am more-so looking at something that just plain works at the time being.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (SELECT
            UPPER(ta.DB_NAME) AS [DB_Name]
        FROM
            [CMS].[dbo].[TABLE_A] AS ta
        UNION
        SELECT
            UPPER(tb.DB_NAME) AS [DB_Name]
        FROM
            [CMS].[dbo].[TABLE_B] as tb
        ) AS SQLresults
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM
        [CMS].[dbo].[TABLE_C_EXCEPTIONS] as tc
    WHERE
        SQLresults.[DB_Name] = tc.DB_NAME)
ORDER BY    SQLresults.[DB_Name]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another option using EXCEPT. I added a group by in each half of the union because it was not clear in your original post if DB_NAME is unique in your tables.

```
select DatabaseName
from
(
    SELECT UPPER(ta.DB_NAME) AS DatabaseName
    FROM [CMS].[dbo].[TABLE_A] AS ta
    GROUP BY UPPER(ta.DB_NAME)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT UPPER(tb.DB_NAME) AS DatabaseName
    FROM [CMS].[dbo].[TABLE_B] as tb
    GROUP BY UPPER(tb.DB_NAME) 
) x
group by DatabaseName
having count(*) < 2
EXCEPT
(
    select DN_Name 
    from CMS.dbo.TABLE_C_EXCEPTION
)
```

Comment: This made sense to me. Thank you very much, Sean!

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `union all` and aggregation:

```
select ab.*
from ((select upper(name) as name, 'A' as which
       from CMS.dbo.TABLE_A
      ) union all
      (select upper(name), 'B' as which
       from CMS.dbo.TABLE_B
      )
     ) ab
where not exists (select 1
                  from CMS.dbo.TABLE_C_EXCEPTION e
                  where upper(e.name) = ab.name
                 )
having count(distinct which) <> 2;
```

SQL Server is case-insensitive by default.  I left the `upper()`s in the query in case your installation is case sensitive.

Comment: Appreciate such a quick response, Gordon. I replaced _name_ with the appropriate column name, and table A, B, and C with the actual names of the tables, etc. No deal there, I believe.

What I don't understand is the:
''A' as which'
and
''B' as which'
along with
'having count(distinct which) <> 2;'

I understand we're trying to filter out results where there aren't 2, but I don't necessarily grasp what's happening. Additionally, I am now getting the return:

Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 9
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'ab'.

Not sure if that helps any.